# How to create custom scrollable views in android?

Tags: android, design-patterns, android-listview, android-fragments

I have to implement custom view that loads content from remote location and keep them adding one below another. The one option is to use Custom adapters and listviews. Other might be using fragments. Which one is preferred way in android?

Comment: fragments? what do thay have to do with your problem?

Comment: Well i thought i could use fragments to display the same content listview and custom adapters were used for. I am new in android i may be totally wrong?

Comment: custom adapter will do the job i think